# My character suddenly stopping in my unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have tried every solution but I couldnt solve this problem, when my character turning left or right it stucks pls help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is no invisible Collider and also make sure that your Players collider are not overlapping
If your script is the problem then i suggest to download the standard assets pack from the asset store and use the default movement script.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have checked there is no invisible colliders and it seems like there is no problem and I stuck in corner